# Germany Alexa skills with a UK amazon.co.uk account

Tags: alexa

I have a UK amazon.co.uk and Audible account with all my Audiobooks and I like speaking to Alexa on my Echo in English.

Now I have moved to Germany and I cannot seem to get German Alexa skills (from amazon.de) while signed on to my UK account. I do not want to change my country settings, as I will then no longer be able to order English audiobooks via Audible.co.uk any more (and I might lose my past purchases).

Please advise if there is a way to have German Alexa skills on an amazon.co.uk account.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you're going to be able to do this with just one Amazon account.

The only option I can think of is to use the Household Accounts in the settings to add a second German account to the device.

You might have to switch between accounts to use the different sets of skills.

https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-and-use-multiple-accounts-on-amazon-echo/