# Amazon Echo in France but I want everything to be english speaking

Tags: alexa

I live in france. I have changed the language to English and the location to UK.  I now have Alexa speaking English. However, I am having trouble getting echo to play BBC radio channels. Alexa cannot understand the commands. Also when I ask for my flash briefing, it is all in french. How can I have all my info and radio etc english?

Comment: Maybe related: https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/281/how-to-use-english-alexa-skills-on-my-german-echo-dot

Comment: And this question https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/germany-alexa-skills-with-a-uk-amazon-co-uk-account/3698#3698

Comment: And this search result https://www.digitaltrends.com/home/how-to-change-alexas-voice/